# Usepackage from a superdirectory

Tags: packages

I have several folders/subdirectories (within a main directory) having a Tex projects (of their own) that require a single style file that is in the main directory.

Rather than having a copy of the style file for each subdirectory, I would like just direct TeX to the single style file I have. This will save me work, whenever I would update the style file.

Is there any way to achieve that: To usepackage from a superdirectory?

Comment: Put that style file in your local texmf tree (for mac users, it can be `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`) and then run `sudo texhash` in the terminal. Then you can `\usepackage` it everywhere.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te

Comment: @Stephen Is there a way to do it, without putting that style file into the local texmf tree?

Comment: You can also use relative path: `\usepackage{../mypkg}`.

Comment: @Stephen Please don't - the argument to `usepackage` is supposed to be a file name, not a path, and `TEXINPUTS` or similar the expected ways to deal with this

Comment: OK. Thank you for your comment@JosephWright I just think this is a possible way but not recommend it.

Comment: you can use `TEXINPUTS=..//:  pdflatex yourfile`  then it will find any file below the parent.

Comment: Did I miss somebody suggesting using your home `texmf` directory? Typically, this might be `~/texmf/tex/latex/mypkg/mypkg.sty` for example. No need for `sudo` or `texhash` and you don't have to remember `TEXINPUTS` every time you compile. You could also just link to a single copy, rather than duplicating, but that can get muddled more easily.